# Do constant and reinterpret cast happen at compile time?

Tags: c++, casting, c++03

I have read that `static_cast` happens at compile time and `dynamic_cast` happens at run time thus are slower than `static_cast`. A `dynamic_cast` can either return a null ptr (when using with a pointer) or otherwise throw a bad cast exception. My question is what about `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` do they happen at compile time or run-time ? I would think that interpret cast happens at run-time since it behaves like `dynamic_cast` indicating if the cast was successful. Am i correct ? What about const_cast is that compile time ?

Comment: None of the casts happen at compile time. You only have the data at runtime, in general.

Comment: @manasij7479 That is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The dynamic cast is the only that needs to be "calculated" in run-time. All other casts are calculated in compile-time.

- The machine code for a `static_cast` is a fixed function based on the type you are casting FROM and TO.
- The machine code for a `const_cast` is in fact nothing more than allow a const value to be passed as no-const or vice-versa. So it can be resolved in compile-time
- For `reinterpret_cast`, the machine code can be resolved in compile-time as well. Once it's nothing more than "look to a pointer that is pointing to a type A with the eyes of who is looking for the type B".
- The `dynamic_cast` needs to resolve virtual tables and adjust the correct addresses of virtual methods based on the type FROM and TO. That's why it's more complex!

Answer (score 4):

- `const_cast`

  - used to add or remove const-ness - is entirely compile time - it doesn't affect the actual code generated for run-time execution - only whether the compiler stops with an error when it sees the code attempting to write to a `const` value.
  - used to add or remove volatility - happens at compile time, but the compiler may then generate typically more and/or slower code when `volatile` is added, or less/faster code when volatile's removed; these code changes affect runtime performance (and correctness, if volatility's needed)
- `reinterpret_cast` changes the compiler's perspective on data and may result in different code being executed at runtime; while there's no runtime cost involved with the cast itself, the cast-to type might need more or less code (and processing cycles) in the surrounding context of use than the cast-from type needed (if it even supported those semantics of usage)
- `static_cast` also picks cast-to-type appropriate code to insert at compile time - much as a `reinterpret_cast` - but the data itself may undergo an extra conversion (`static_cast<T>(x)` is equivalent to `T temp(x);`)... the conversion clearly can add code and runtime overhead
- `dynamic_cast`: the compiler considers its knowledge of the actual types involved.

  - If the code context in which the `dynamic_cast` is performed only knows about the cast-from object via a pointer or reference from some other code, and is unable to determine the real runtime type of the variable, it's obliged to use Run-Time Type Information (RTTI) to see whether/how the runtime type relates to the cast-to type.
  - If the actual cast-from type is known at compile time, the compiler can substitute the equivalent of a `static_cast` between the two pointer or reference types.  Using its knowledge of the actual types it can determine whether the pointer/reference needs to be adjusted (e.g. adding or subtracting some number of bytes corresponding to the offset of one of the classes in the other) or ends up being effectively a `reinterpret_cast` of the same address.

Answer (score 2):

A very detailed specification exists here that answers your question:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Effectively, reinterpret_cast<> leaves no run-time footprint.

const_cast is compile time as well, no code needs to be generated.